# What is the next(){} inside object?

Tags: javascript

While looking through for-of loop I see the following code:

```
var iterable = {
  [Symbol.iterator]() { /* 1. I don't understand, will look later*/
    return {
      i: 0,
      next() { /* 2. New to me how next(){} is used inside object? */
        if (this.i < 3) {
          return { value: this.i++, done: false };
        }
        return { value: undefined, done: true };
      }
    };
  }
};

for (var value of iterable) {
  console.log(value);
}
// 0
// 1
// 2
```

To simplify my question, I am trying to understand with my own logic like this:

```
function bar(){
  return 1;
}
var obj = {foo: 1, bar(){}}
console.log(obj); /* I get nothing error, so this is good */
console.log(obj.bar()); 
/* Just trying to know if this works, but I get undefined*/
```

So what is the use of func(){} inside the object literal? I have only seen the `property:value` declaration inside object literal.

Comment: `next()` is an iterator generator. So it will add +1 to the `i` variable in each iteration

Comment: See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next

Comment: @Juhana In your possible duplicate question even I can see `property:value` declaration inside object literal that is what interest of me is without `property:value`.

Comment: Also, in your second block of code, *"Just trying to know if this works, but I get undefined"* – of course you do, because `obj.bar()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: My key question is using next(){} inside object literal which is really not `property:value` declaration. I have even seen only using `property:value`

Comment: Read the duplicate more carefully. It doesn't use the property:value syntax.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal objects don't need to have strictly `property: value` assignment, they can contain objects as well. If you think about it, a function can merely be an object and that can be assigned to the property. Read up on object literals here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

It's an extremely powerful concept when you wrap your head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next() {}` within an object is an es6 shortform.

In pre es6 it would be written as `next: function() {}` for your own logic you can use a compiler such as Babel or just write it as

```
var obj = {
  foo: 1, 
  bar: function(){ 
    // return data here 
  }
}
```

Essentially, objects can contain other objects and those objects can also be functions. It's quite powerful when you wrap your head around it.

Edit: formatted answer for better legibilty

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your simplified question:
First you define `bar` as a function which returns `1`.
Then inside the `obj` you define it as blank function.
When you pass a function inside the object it gets the `key` as function name and value of this function.

this code below

```
var obj = {foo: 1, bar(){}}
```

is equal to

```
var bar = function() {}
var obj = {foo: 1, bar: bar}
```

however if you do it like this

```
var obj = {foo: 1,bar(){return 1}}
console.log(obj.bar()) //output will be 1
```

Comment: `var obj = {foo: 1, bar(){}}` is equal to `var obj = {foo: 1, bar: bar}`, but not to `var obj = {foo: 1, bar: bar()}`, because there `bar` would be immediately called because of the `()` and the result would be stored in the property `bar`

Comment: Yeah. You're right. Thanks for pointing it. Edited the answer

Comment: Plus one for your answer. But couldn't accept both answer.

Comment: It should be noted that `var obj = {foo: 1,bar(){return 1}}` will only work in ES6 compliant browsers. Even IE 11 lacks a lot of ES6 feature support. Reference: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/